# Rails 3 time output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, frontend

I'm now working on my output of the feeds I'm taking in from some site. What I'm currently doing is Time, and i want it to be displayed in a maybe, little be special way.. like this..

```
today, 14:12
yesterday, 15:34
27/12, 15:24
```

i have this in my code

```
= news.entry_published.strftime("%d/%m, %H:%M")
```

That gives me an error saying

```
undefined method `strftime' for "2010-12-30 19:26:00.000000":String
```

And it dosn't do what i want with the days..

Edit:

```
- @date = DateTime.strptime(news.entry_published, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
= @date.strftime("%d/%m, %H:%M")
```

Now works, and gives this output

```
30/12, 19:26
```

But i still have to check if it is today, yesterday or just another day.
Cheers, Oluf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue now is that you want a date, but you actually have a datetime.

It should be easy enough to check if the date is today doing something like...

```
@date.to_date == Date.today
```

Yesterday...

```
@date.to_date == Date.yesterday
```

Comment: Hi, so that didn't work, so i looked up in my terminal and it says this.. >> Date.today
=> Fri, 31 Dec 2010
>> Date.yesterday
=> Wed, 29 Dec 2010

Comment: Is an error being thrown?  Make sure you do this comparison before that @date.strftime("%d/%m, %H:%M") line, or else you're converting a DateTime to a string and then to a date, which could give you unexpected results.

Comment: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6237-date-bug-in-rails-3#ticket-6237-6

Answer (score 1):

As error message suggests, datatype for **entry_published** is String.
I believe problem is that in database **entry_published** is varchar datatype, right?

To solve this you have to do one of following things:
 - Change **entry_published** database datatype to datetime
 - First convert this string to Date and afterwards apply this **strftime** method.

Comment: Or convert it to a `Time` object.

Comment: Thanks that worked, i'd updated my question, but i still need some help with the "today" and "yesterday" thing..